# Angular 4 Material Tabs Load on Tab Select

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Is it possible to achieve lazy loading on Angular Material Tabs? Otherwise I would need a way to run a method when entering a tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `selectChange` event provided by `<md-tab-group>`. It fires when a tab selection is changed. From the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api):

> @Output() selectChange : Event emitted when the tab selection has
>   changed.

In your template:

```
<md-tab-group (selectChange)="tabSelectionChanged($event)">
  <md-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">
    This tab will load some morecontents after 5 seconds.
    <p>{{ moreContents }}</p>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

... and in your typescript code:

```
tabSelectionChanged(event){
    // Get the selected tab
    let selectedTab = event.tab;
    console.log(selectedTab);

    // Call some method that you want 
    this.someMethod();
}
```

Link to [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7yrpdv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: `(selectedTabChange)` for Angular 6

Comment: @JanisP it's actually Angular 5 (material 5).

Answer (score 7):

I know the question was about angular-material 5.x.x, but for those who arrive here and aren't paying attention, angular-material 6 supports lazy-loading tab content natively https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Angular Material Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading):

Lazy Loading

By default, the tab contents are eagerly loaded. Eagerly loaded tabs will initalize the child components but not inject them into the DOM until the tab is activated.

If the tab contains several complex child components or the tab's contents rely on DOM calculations during initialization, it is advised to lazy load the tab's content.

Tab contents can be lazy loaded by declaring the body in a **ng-template** with the **matTabContent** attribute.

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      The First Content
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      The Second Content
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation reads

> While `<md-tab-group>` is used to switch between views within a single
>   route, `<nav md-tab-nav-bar>` provides a tab-like UI for navigating
>   between routes.

By using this method,you can make each of the tab separate routes and hence each of the page loads each time the route is activated.

```
<nav md-tab-nav-bar>
  <a md-tab-link
     *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
     [routerLink]="link"
     routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="rla.isActive">
    {{tabLink.label}}
  </a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Please find more info [here](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview) under **Tabs and navigation** section.