# How can I load components added in tab using angular4?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am working with angular4 and angular material2.

I have the following code

```
<md-tab-group color="primary">
        <md-tab label="Employee">
            <app-employee></app-employee>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Department">
            <app-department></app-department>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Attendance">
            <app-attendance></app-attendance>
        </md-tab>
    </md-tab-group>
```

Now all the components are loaded initially but I want load the particular component whenever i'm selecting the corresponding tab.

Answer (score 5):

NB. Angular Material has been recently updated and components have been renamed, e.g. `<md-tab>` is now `<mat-tab>`. DOC: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api

What you want is to **lazy-load** the tab contents. As per the Angular material docs, it doesn't seem to be possible at this time.

Here are some workarounds:

**Option 1. Activate the child component's based on their tabgroup's `selectedIndex` property**

```
<mat-tab-group color="primary" #tabGroup>
  <mat-tab label="Employee">
    <app-employee *ngIf="tabGroup.selectedIndex === 0"></app-employee>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Department" #tabDepartment>
    <app-department *ngIf="tabGroup.selectedIndex === 1"></app-department>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Attendance">
    <app-attendance *ngIf="tabGroup.selectedIndex === 2"></app-attendance>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**Option 2. Listen to the `selectedIndexChange()` event on the tab group**

And load some content dynamically in the event handler for this event.

Something like:

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedIndexChange)="loadDynamicContent()">
  <mat-tab>
    {{ dynamicContent }}
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

I found this idea here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45980187

Answer (score 3):

An even cleaner solution is possible by using `*matTabContent`, which decorates the `ng-template` tags and reads out the template from it.

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Employee">
    <app-employee *matTabContent></app-employee>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Department">
    <app-department *matTabContent></app-department>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Attendance">
    <app-attendance *matTabContent></app-attendance>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Keep in mind that the every time you open a tab, the corresponding component will be (re)initialized.

Comment: @JsonK if i want load only once , just first time that tab is selected ,how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML File**

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedIndexChange)="selectTab($event)">
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
      <app-control1 *ngIf="selectedTab === 0"></app-control1>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 2">
      <app-control2 *ngIf="selectedTab === 1"></app-control2>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**TS File**

> declare new property

```
selectedTab = 0;
```

> update property on selected Index Change event

```
selectTab(event) {
this.selectedTab = event;
}
```